# Utilising AnimatePresence from framer motion to create a exit animation for a motion.div

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

Im am trying to create a side menu that pops in and out when the menu/close button is pressed using framer motion.
When the menu button is first clicked the menu will slide out from the left hand side of the screen and the button changes to closed.
When now the close button is pressed the menu should slide back out however, it just disappears with no animation

I tried to wrap the motion.div in AnimaiatePresence so that i can then add a exit animation as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const menuItems = ["Home", "Projects", "Blog", "Recipes"];

const menuVariant = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, x: "-100vw" },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    x: 0,
    transition: { style: "tween", duration: 0.75 },
  },
  exit: {
    x: "-100vw",
    transition: { ease: "easeInOut" },
  },
};

const SideMenu = () => {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <motion.div
        className="flex flex-col px-10 bg-orange-400 max-h-full w-2/5 rounded-r-full round"
        variants={menuVariant}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        exit="exit"
      >
        {menuItems.map((item) => (
          <button className="my-3 text-4xl text-left">{item}</button>
        ))}
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default SideMenu;
```

The above component is utilised in the following home page code

```
"use client";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";
import SideMenu from "../components/sideMenu";



const buttonVariant = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  show: { opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 1, delay: 0.5 } },
};

export default function Home() {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <motion.button
        className={`m-10 p-4 border-2 rounded-3xl ${
          menuState ? "border-red-500" : "border-sky-500"
        }`}
        variants={buttonVariant}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        onClick={() => {
          setMenuState(!menuState);
        }}
      >
        {menuState ? "Close" : "Menu"}
      </motion.button>
      {menuState ? <SideMenu /> : <></>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Will you share more of your code? It's hard to help when we don't have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Exit animations only work if the element is exiting the React tree. You aren't conditionally rendering the `motion.div`, so the exit animation won't work. The [first example in their AnimatePresence docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/) is a good frame of reference.

Comment: @Rico I just edited the original post to contain the remaining code. Ill take a look at the docs but any additional assistance would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnimatePresence` only works when it's **direct children** are being removed from the React tree. You need to move your conditional rendering logic to the `<SideMenu />`:

```
const SideMenu = () => {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {/* Moved trigger button into the SideMenu */}
      <motion.button
        className={`m-10 p-4 border-2 rounded-3xl ${
          menuState ? "border-red-500" : "border-sky-500"
        }`}
        variants={buttonVariant}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="show"
        onClick={() => {
          setMenuState(!menuState);
        }}
      >
        {menuState ? "Close" : "Menu"}
      </motion.button>

      {/* Conditionally show menu if menuState is 'true' */}
      <AnimatePresence>
        {menuState && (
          <motion.div
            className="flex flex-col px-10 bg-orange-400 max-h-full w-2/5 rounded-r-full round"
            variants={menuVariant}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="show"
            exit="exit"
          >
            {menuItems.map((item) => (
              <button key={item} className="my-3 text-4xl text-left">
                {item}
              </button>
            ))}
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here's [a working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vigilant-danilo-483th9?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40008356hjl565sws%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40002356h1gdo1mo8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40005356h2mlk9yvf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40007356hdpu4ur3g%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B54.84319022166025%252C45.15680977833975%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq4e34q40002356h1gdo1mo8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40002356h1gdo1mo8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clq4e34q40007356hdpu4ur3g%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40007356hdpu4ur3g%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40006356h2f008bbc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40006356h2f008bbc%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4e34q40005356h2mlk9yvf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40003356hpkgp2ymx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40004356hbx176vby%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clq1okc400004edeq522l8u4c%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40005356h2mlk9yvf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq4e34q40003356hpkgp2ymx%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) if you need more help.

Comment: Ahhhhh makes alot of sense, ty for the help :))

Comment: No problem @Andradz! If you found it helpful, feel free to [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).